# Errors were encountered while processing: linux-image / headers / generic

Tags: kernel, updates, unetbootin

I tried to update my machine through the Update Manager and found some errors.

First, before I get to the problem, I feel I should mention that my OS (10.04) is mounted on a portable HDD that boots using **Unetbootin**. (I take it with me around campus and "borrow" the universities hardware, it's much lighter than a laptop.)

When I update through the Update Manager I get the following:

```
dpkg: error processing linux-headers-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-2.6.32-40-generic
 linux-image-2.6.32-41-generic
 linux-headers-2.6.32-33-generic
 linux-headers-2.6.32-40-generic
 linux-headers-2.6.32-37-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-image-2.6.32-33-generic
 linux-headers-2.6.32-41-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-image-2.6.32-37-generic
 linux-headers-generic
```

I'm not sure what to do. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Could you try `dpkg --configure -a` in a terminal? What output do you get?

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get -f install
```

is generally used to fix broken dependencies

Comment: Yea, I tried that, but I get the same errors... :/

Comment: Any other ideas?

Comment: Possible to do with nvidia driver?  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1489669 is similar not identical.

Comment: Good idea, I'll give that a try and let ya'll know.